# How to generate non-decreasing integer n-tuples in Python?

Tags: python

Consider the tuple `(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)` with each satisfying `1 <= x_i <= m and 
x_1 <= x_2 <= ... <= x_n`. I know that in Python, I can generate all the `n-tuples` satisfying the bound `1 <= x_i <= m` using the following:
`list_of_tuples = list(product(range(1,m+1), repeat = n))` but this will return a list of tuples that do not satisfy the non-decreasing property of the tuple. How do I generate such sequences?

As an example, say that `n=3 and m=2` then

`list_of_tuples = [(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2)]`

However, we notice that `(1,2,1),(2,1,1),(2,1,2),(2,2,1)` do not obey the non-decreasing property. For instance in `(1,2,1)` we see that `x_2 = 2` is **not** less than or equal to `x_3 = 1`.

Comment: Have you considered using the built-in `sorted` function to sort your list of tuples? You could use the `sorted` function to sort the tuples inside your list. Your question is unclear, so I can't help you much further. Can you provide an example of desired inout and output?

Comment: do you need *all* of the non-decreasing tuples?

Comment: @Joel I made an edit. Is it clear now?

Comment: Try `sorted(list_of_tuples, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1], x[2]))`

Comment: Are you just looking for `combinations_with_replacement(range(1,m+1), n)`?  (I'm not making this an answer because I think it might be a dupe, if so.)

Comment: This could also be done with a simple recursion, as I demonstrated in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) does the job:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as cwr
for tup in cwr(range(1, m+1), n):
    do_whatever_with(tup)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. How efficient is this method? I want to this for large values of $n.$ Do you think it is feasible to use this method?

Comment: @SuperMario: It's going to be more feasible than filtering the `itertools.product` output, but iterating over all those tuples at all is probably infeasible no matter how you generate them.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
def list_of_tuples(n, m):
 return set(tuple(sorted(tup)) for tup in product(range(1,m+1), repeat = n))
```

For n=3 and m=2, it results in:

```
{(1, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2)}
```

This is not very efficient, though, but perhaps this does not matter.

Comment: Actually, my goal is to test whether the sum of elements of the tuple is equal to their product, with m = 2n. So for various values of n, I have to generate non-decreasing tuples with each element ranging from 1 to 2n and then I want to iterate over them and check if the sum of elements of the tuple is equal to their product. I guess if it is efficient it will be better.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that I got exactly what you're looking for, but perhaps this code snippet might work:

```
list_of_tuples = list(product(range(1,m+1), repeat = n))
my_set = set([tuple(sorted(t)) for t in list_of_tuples])
```

Using the `set` operation you keep a single copy of each duplicate, and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

This code could be done pretty easily with recursion, without using `itertools`.

```
def non_decreasing(n, m):
  if n==0:
    return []
  if n==1:
    return [[i] for i in range(1,m+1)]
  return [[i] + t for t in non_decreasing(n-1, m) for i in range(1,t[0]+1)]
```

Example:

```
In [23]: non_decreasing(2,3)
Out[23]: [[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 3]]
```